Is there one second messenger molecule for each hormone?
I have learnt about a number of different types of second messenger molecules including cAMP, IP$_3$, Ca$^{2+}$ and DAGs. Hormones interact with signal proteins in the cell membrane which transduces a signal into second messenger molecules inside the cell. I haven't been able to find out how the hormones map onto these second messengers. For example, there could one second messenger for each hormone and so eg. maybe ADH and only ADH triggers cAMP. Then glucagon would have a different second messenger molecule etc.
I got the impression that this is not the case however and things are more complex. Maybe each second messenger molecule has its own function in the cell and different hormones trigger different amounts of second messengers? So like, maybe ADH triggers cAMP a little bit, and glucagon triggers it a lot, but LH never triggers cAMP. And then ADH triggers IP$_3$ a lot and glucagon leaves it unchanged, etc.
Anyway that's just two possible explanations that I came up with. So, how do hormones map onto second messenger molecules?

There are typically multiple different second messenger systems used by a given hormone, and multiple hormones use the same second messenger system.
Second messengers aren't really a property of the hormone/ligand, they are a property of the receptor, so you'll want to look for information about different receptors for a ligand to know what second messengers are involved.
Take ADH/vasopressin for example: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasopressin
Vasopressin binding can result in both calcium release and cAMP increases.
Same with glucagon: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucagon_receptor
Specificity comes from expression, co-expression, and localization. Only cells that express a receptor will be affected by a hormone. Only receptors for a second messenger that are expressed in that cell type will be affected by second messenger changes. And finally, second messenger signalling is often local, so it's not as if calcium for example increases in equal amounts throughout an entire cell, it increases and has effects locally and is sequestered by calcium binding proteins as it diffuses away.
